# I moved my source directory and can no longer push to Heroku

Tags: heroku, branch, kiln, hg-git

I've been happily using heroku to beta test a Rails app, and recently hit a snag. I prefer Mercurial to git and have been using hg-git to push my app to Heroku. This was working fine until I branched my repo (doing a branch by cloning in kiln, if that matters). My folder structure used to look like this:

```
~/Code/MyApp
```

And is now:

```
~/Code/MyApp/trunk
~/Code/MyApp/current
```

Where `trunk` is the old 'root' copy, and `current` is the recently created branch. I did try going back to my old directory structure (just the root `MyApp` folder) and that didn't change anything.

Now when I push to heroku, it does this:

```
pushing to git+ssh://git@heroku.com:myapp.git
importing Hg objects into Git
converting revision 7491a23b35ee405325bb7a024f3cbee047a59dcd
*snipped all the revisions*
creating and sending data
```

And then just stops. No errors, and when I check the site, the change didn't happen. And there's nothing in the error logs either. So what gives? I'd rather not create a separate git repo in the app; that'll get messy quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're not doing the equivalent of a `git push heroku master`, but instead pushing your new branch.

Heroku will only deploy the master branch.

For more on topic branches, see here: http://neilmiddleton.com/deploying-topic-branches-to-heroku/